# Compiling Error - exit status 1 for DHT11 using Arduino UNO (code/process/connections same as website given bellow)

Tags: arduino-uno

*https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/MisterBotBreak/how-to-use-temperature-and-humidity-dht-sensors-9e5975*

**Copied Error Message:**

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"

In file included from C:\Users\soumy\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DHT-sensor-library-master\DHT_U.cpp:15:0:

C:\Users\soumy\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DHT-sensor-library-master\DHT_U.h:36:10: fatal error: Adafruit_Sensor.h: No such file or directory

 #include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>

          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

compilation terminated.

exit status 1

Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.



This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

**The code:**

```
#define DHTPIN 2     
#define DHTTYPE DHT11   

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("DHTxx test!");

  dht.begin();
}

void loop() {
  
  delay(2000);
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  float f = dht.readTemperature(true);

  if (isnan(h) || isnan(t) || isnan(f)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
    return;
  }

  float hif = dht.computeHeatIndex(f, h);
  float hic = dht.computeHeatIndex(t, h, false);

  Serial.print("Humidity: ");
  Serial.print(h);
  Serial.print(" %\t");
  Serial.print("Temperature: ");
  Serial.print(t);
  Serial.print(" *C ");
  Serial.print(f);
  Serial.print(" *F\t");
  Serial.print("Heat index: ");
  Serial.print(hic);
  Serial.print(" *C ");
  Serial.print(hif);
  Serial.println(" *F");
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: The compiler couldn't find the file `Adafruit_Sensor.h`. Have you installed the Adafruit sensor library correctly?

Comment: @chrisl i didnt add the adafruit library, now it's working. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't download the "Adafruit Sensor Library"
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Sensor
It ran after I added it.